# Delete (make null) duplicate field values

Tags: python, duplicates, arcpy

i've searched for a solution for this but haven't found a complete one. I have dozens of tables that each contain thousands of line features.  whenever a line feature is split another record is created but the new line (record) still has the old ASSETID. This means a duplicate ASSETID is born.  Is maintenance python script that can find all the duplicate ASSETID's and make them null?  this would leave just the original ASSETID, i have a script that would be run afterwards that would populate the ASSETID field with a new, randomly generated ASSETID. i've been able to create lists all the duplicate values, a list of how many times a value occurs, a new column on the table that has a 'Y' if value is repeated, etc. but have yet been able to remove duplicate field values while retaining everything else in the row.

Comment: I think you should research/ask this at the [gis.se] Stack Exchange instead.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a list of duplicate `ASSETID`s, you can use an [ArcPy UpdateCursor](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-data-access/updatecursor-class.htm) to modify only that attribute.

```
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(feature_class, ["ASSETID"]) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        if row[0] in unique_id_list:   # if the ASSETID is in the list
            row[0] = None
            cursor.updateRow(row)
```

This will modify *all* rows that have that `ASSETID` value, however, and not leave the "original" intact. You'd need an additional list of the original (by another unique identifier, e.g. `OBJECTID`) and exclude those, e.g.:

```
if row[0] in unique_id_list and row[1] not in original_id_list:
```